# Why do I need to specify the type of data?

Tags: java

Greatings there from the absolutely beginning of the coding way, I'm talking, less than a week (than 4 days, if to be correct).
So, here's my problem. I made a class `User` and then gave it some variables (sorry if the way I'm writing is very casual and not programming-like).

```
public class User 
{
    String name;
    short age;
    int height;
```

Then I created some constructors. That's one of them:

```java
public User(String name,short age,int height) {
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.height=height;
    System.out.println(name);
    System.out.println("Age: "+age);
    System.out.println("Height: "+height);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Afterwards, in the `main` method I made a subject of the class `User` with indicated aomounts of variables:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    User user1=new User("Dan",20,190);
}
```

But when I run the programm, I get an error saying that there arent any constructor of (String,int,int) type. Meanwhile, if write `(short)`,that is, specify the datatype, programm works. Why do Java see the the number matching the type of amount which `short` requires as `int`?

Comment: Because 20 really is an `int` (meaning that immediate number values are `int`s by default, because that's how the language is defined) and since it could be an `int` that does not fit a `short` the compiler wants you to be explicit about it.

Comment: Also, what you're doing is not called "specifying the data type". The correct term for future reference is "casting".

Comment: [A quick read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) on the topic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java number literals are at `int`s, so 20 is an `int` which is not converted to short implicitely (except in some initialisations).

The compiler is then looking for a method that takes **at least** an int as second parameter. Your definition accept **at most** shorts (`short`s are strict subset of `int`s). Then compiler rejects the call as unresolved.

When you write `(short)20` then you order the compiler to shorter down the 32 bits `int` to a 16 bits `short` value. It is too dangerous (some ints values can be represented as shorts) to make it implicitly thus you need to write it by yourself and enforce the conversion (provided that you know what you are doing).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error is telling you that age is not of type `short`, (it automatically takes it as `int` unless you tell him otherwise)

Try this, this way you're telling the compiler your age is type `short`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String name = "Dan";
        short age = 20;
        int height = 190;
        User user1=new User(name,age,height);
}
```

Comment: Ok but the trick is then in `short age = 20`!!!

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès indeed, "automatically takes it as int"